# iPhone Reporting Wrong Location when connected to WiFi

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi

My iPhone 13 Pro Max (iOS 16.1.2) and my partner’s iPhone Xs Max (16.2) are reporting incorrect location info.  We recently moved places< this was about 3 months ago.

At the beginning, both of our phones were reporting the wrong location while connected to WiFi. My phone fixed itself in 2–3 weeks. I’ve read that this due to Apple’s database for home location updates once a month, but my partner's phone is still reporting wrong location while connected to our WiFi.

What have I done:

- Fully reset our router, changed the SSID, changed the password. Our public IP also changed.
- Deleted all WiFi networks that her phone remembered.
- Reset all location and privacy settings on her phone
- Set home location on every possible app including Apple Maps, Google Maps, Life360
- Disabled and then enabled location services and Find My functionality
- Multiple reboots for her phone

I’ve been trying to Google around for a fix, but I can’t find anything. I know one option is to do full reset, but she is not keen on that.

Does anyone know what else can we try?

Comment: You say that it reports the wrong location when connected to WiFi.  How far off is the reported location versus your actual location.  When you turn off WiFi, what location get”s reported?

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to specify that. The location shown is her old address. Even tho we are using completely different router, SSID and we have a different public IP.

Comment: So, just to be clear, the phone is showing her current location as your old address?  What happens when you open the Maps app?  What does it show?

Comment: Yes, the phone is showing the old home address while we are at the new address. Google and Apple Maps are also showing the previous address. It only shows the correct location when using 4G. So it somehow associates current Wifi as the old home address.